# What is the name of this sliding selection list?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

I want to implement this type of sliding selection list in my kotlin based android studio app. but, I don't know what actually it is. so, plz help me

[image: Image from hirect login page]

Answer (score 1):

Its Called **Spinner**

In Xml File implement like this

```
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Follow this link for more details
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spinner-in-kotlin/

Comment: No bro i know spinner but see the bottom in that image